# PhoneGap icons not automatically set on command line build for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm working on a PhoneGap project and testing a lot with the online build tool. Now i try to build the project from the command line with the following command:

```
phonegap build ios
```

My project is setup for PhoneGap 2.9.0 and in the online build tool everything works fine. But when i try to generate a iOS project with the command line tools, the icons are not setup correctly.

PhoneGap creates the iOS project with a standard Resources folder with default icons and splash screens. In my PhoneGap project i also have icons and splash screens with a reference from the config.xml. The iOS project does take some of the icon references i created but some of them it uses the default icons from the resources folder...

Has someone else has this problem with the command line build?

[image]